# What information can the ISP see when BitTorrent is in encrypted mode?

Tags: bittorrent

What kind of information can the ISP see when a BitTorrent data packet is passing through their network if BitTorrent is in encrypted mode?

Comment: This Reddit thread may also be of interest to you: [What does a SSL tracker encrypt?](https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/2i4zzc/private_trackers_with_ssl_support/)

Answer (score 4):

According to [the inventor](https://torrentfreak.com/interview-with-bram-cohen-the-inventor-of-bittorrent/):

> The so-called ‘encryption’ of BitTorrent traffic isn’t really encryption, it’s obfuscation. It provides no anonymity whatsoever, and only temporarily evades traffic shaping.

And:

> As I’ve said before, protocol encryption is at best a temporary hack around ISP rate limiting, until identification techniques are put in place which use transfer patterns rather than packet inspection to identify traffic.

In [this research paper](https://www.iis.se/docs/hjelmvik_breaking.pdf), they

> show
>   how even obfuscated application layer protocols, such as BitTorrent’s MSE protocol and Skype, can
>   be identified by fingerprinting statistically measurable properties of TCP and UDP sessions.

Comment: So can I say ISP sees a BitTorrent packet as a typical TCP/IP packet if they are not performing a deep inspection?

Comment: @shamikaDharmasiri:  Many ISPs actually use these techniques both for traffic shaping and to properly analyze/log what is actually happening.  Assuming that they don't because it's complex is simply an unreliable assumption.